# rails 4 nested forms don't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I know there's a lot of open questions regarding this around here already but none really helped me.

My main model is being saved properly, all the data is in the post-data, but it just doesn't save the nested models!

Thanks heaps.. Is it anything about the permitted parameters or attr_accessors? Something I suspect.. I didn't really find any documentation on that..

This is my code:

products_controller.rb

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :netprice, :vat, :price, :unit_count,         :unit, :category, :img, :origin, :originid, :producer, :stock, :discount, :stories_attributes, :origins_attributes, :id)
    end
end

def new
    @product = Product.new
    3.times { @product.stories.build }
    @product.origins.build
    @categories = []
    Category.all.each do |category|
    @categories.push([category.name, category.name])
    end

end

def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
    else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
end
```

origin.rb

```
class Origin < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :stories_attributes, :origins_attributes
    has_many :stories
    has_many :origins
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :stories, allow_destroy:true, :reject_if => lambda { |a|     a[:text].blank?}
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :origins, allow_destroy:true, :reject_if => lambda {|a|      a[:city].blank?}
```

story.rb

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product

end
```

relevant part of the form

```
  <section class="product-story-section">
  <%= f.fields_for :stories do |builder| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= builder.label :yindex, "Y-Index" %><br>
    <%= builder.text_field :yindex %><br>
     <%= builder.label :description, "Story-Text" %><br>
    <%= builder.text_area :description %><br>
     <%= builder.label :img, "Bild-URL" %><br>
    <%= builder.text_field :img %><br>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :productid, value:"1" %><br>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
</section>
<hr>
<%= f.fields_for :origins do |builder| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= builder.label :city, "Stadt" %><br>
    <%= builder.text_field :city %><br>
    <%= builder.label :country, "Land" %><br>
    <%= builder.text_area :country %><br>
    <%= builder.label :geolat, "Geolocation Latitude" %><br>
    <%= builder.text_field :geolat %><br>
    <%= builder.label :geolng, "Geolocation Longitude" %><br>
    <%= builder.text_field :geolng %><br>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>


  Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-24 21:01:16 +0100
  Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"90MXIlzOQg6AcTwwYOkfNsfPuSt1/9UHjqZwHVRnET4=", "product"=>    {"title"=>"9", "description"=>"9", "netprice"=>"9", "vat"=>"9", "price"=>"9",    "unit_count"=>"9", "unit"=>"9", "img"=>"", "originid"=>"99", "origin"=>"", "producer"=>"9",     "stock"=>"9", "discount"=>"9", "stories_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"yindex"=>"9", "description"=>"9",    "img"=>"9", "productid"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"yindex"=>"9", "description"=>"9", "img"=>"9",   "productid"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"yindex"=>"9", "description"=>"9", "img"=>"9", "productid"=>"1"}},  "origins_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"city"=>"9", "country"=>"", "geolat"=>"9", "geolng"=>"9"}}},  "commit"=>"Create Product"}
Unpermitted parameters: img, productid
Unpermitted parameters: img, productid
Unpermitted parameters: img, productid
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `products` (`created_at`, `description`, `discount`, `img`,    `netprice`, `origin`, `originid`, `price`, `producer`, `stock`, `title`, `unit`, `unit_count`, `updated_at`, `vat`) VALUES ('2013-12-24 20:01:16', '9', 9.0, '', 9.0, '', 99, 9.0, '9', 9, '9', '9', 9, '2013-12-24 20:01:16', 9.0)
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/1
Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

New error msg

```
`attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection      model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `end` in your `product_params` method.  This should have raised an error.

You also need to add `stories` and `origins` attributes to the permit list:

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :netprice, :vat, :price, :unit_count, :unit, :category, :img, :origin, :originid, :producer, :stock, :discount, stories_attributes: [:yindex, :description, :image], origins_attributes: [ :city, :country, :geolat], :id)
end
```

**Update:** Add missing attributes to the permit list on `stories_attributes` and `origins_attributes`:

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :netprice, :vat, :price, :unit_count, :unit, :category, :img, :origin, :originid, :producer, :stock, :discount, stories_attributes: [:yindex, :description, :img, :product_id], origins_attributes: [ :city, :country, :geolat, :geolng], :id)
end
```

**Second update:**

You also need to update your product model as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :stories_attributes, :origins_attributes
  ...
end
```

Replace `attr_accessor` with `attr_accessible`.  [`attr_accessible`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class) should be used to allow attributes to mass assignment.

In your controller's create action:

```
# ProductsController
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    ...
end
```

Your `product_params` definitely contains `stories_attributes` and `origins_attributes` and are passed to the `Product.new` method correctly, but because their attributes are not allowed to mass assignment you are not seeing associated `stories` and `origins` created.  Note that `attr_accessor`, a Ruby method, only defines `getters` and `setters` for the attributes but does not allow for mass assignment.

Comment: Actually the end just got in there due to the way I copied things together for the post. However, thanks for the tips on the attributes to the permit list. Unfortunately, it still doesnt work!

Comment: @mgreschke, please see my update.  There were a few attributes missing for `stores_attributes` and `origins_attributes`.  Please give this a try.

Comment: done, still doesnt work. I did some fixes to the names and got rid of the "unpermitted parameter" messages in the console output. But.. still doesnt work. 

What bugs me is, that the SQL request is perfectly fine like always, just not touching the nested attributes. Almost as if it doesnt even try to save the nested parameters..

Comment: I see! Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately it still isn't worked out: I get the error msg that attr_accessible is not supported anymore in rails 4 and outdated. Googling around I found that strong_parameters is actually the new way to go but the way I understood it is that this params.require is exactly that, so I don't know why its not working!Any more clues maybe? Anyways thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @mgreschke, my bad I've edited that answer so many times that I completely forgot that it was Rails4.  Try to get rid of the `attr_accessor` line for the `stories_attributes` and `origins_attributes` altogether.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43882/discussion-between-vee-and-mgreschke)

Comment: You shouldn't use `attr_accessible` anymore - permitted params takes care of that.